# How to simultaneously loop over different lists?

Tags: python, string, list, loops

I'm trying to loop over a list of strings:

```
someplace["Canada", "USA", "England"]

for charNum in range(len(lst)): #charNum the length of the characters
    print(lst[charNum])

for country in range(len([charNum])): #country is the the string
   print(lst[charNum][country])
```

the output I'm trying to achieve is this:

```
c  U  E
a  S  n
n  A  g
a     l 
d     a 
a     n
      d
```

more details:

```
for k in range(len(lst[0])):
    print(lst[0][k])
```

If run this it would print out

```
   c
   a
   n
   a
   d
   a
```

this because it's getting the length of the index 0. But I have to be to loop through the other numbers: 0, 1, 2.

I made some progress I created a nested for-loop:

```
for i in range(len(lst)):  # length of list
    for j in range(len(lst[i])): # length of each string
        print(lst[i][j])
```

Answer (score 4):

use [`itertools.izip_longest`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest) to loop over all simultaneously

```
from itertools import izip_longest  # zip_longest in python 3
places = ["Canada", "USA", "England"]
for chars in izip_longest(*places, fillvalue=' '):
    print(' '.join(chars))
```

#### Output:

```
C U E
a S n
n A g
a   l
d   a
a   n
    d
```

---

#### The Process:

The output of `izip_longest` is:

```
[('C', 'U', 'E'), ('a', 'S', 'n'), ('n', 'A', 'g'), ('a', ' ', 'l'), ('d', ' ', 'a'), ('a', ' ', 'n'), (' ', ' ', 'd')]
```

The `for` loop then assigns each "row" to `chars` sequentially, starting with `('C', 'U', 'E')`

`' '.join(chars)` combines that tuple into a string, with spaces between each list member.  For the first element, that would be `'C U E'`

Comment: I haven't learned to use this method. I learning the beginning steps of python 3.  I stuck on how to change the index number in the for loop.

Comment: @user3339203, I've edited the answer with a more complete explanation of the process

Comment: In this way, we aren't changing the index number. We're accessing members directly

Answer (score 0):

To Internate a List, You Need to have One.

```
my_list = ["Paris"]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
  SomePlaces = ['Canada', 'USA',  'England'] //Array
  for SomePlaces in range(len(lst)):
   print 'Places :', lst[SomePlaces]
```

Note: I didn't test it, sorry if I'm wrong.

Comment: If you don't test your code, don't complain about the downvote. You mixed variable names `SomePlaces` and `lst`, your syntax for commenting was wrong, but most importantly, **your answer didn't even *attempt* to print what OP asked for!**